# SQL to sum data in Snowflake view

Tags: sql, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table with the following fields:

- Date
- Transaction Type
- Transaction Speed
- Company

The table has millions of rows, so I want to summarize the data which will then feed into Power BI.  I want to group by Date, then Transaction Type, then Company, and sum the values in Transaction Speed.

I'm very new to SQL and have created some basic views, but am having trouble creating the summarization.  Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Usually tools like Power BI will write the SQL for you and you just point them to the table. Are you sure you need to create a view at all?

Comment: I couldn't find a way in the Power BI query to summarize the data on query, so it is pulling in too many rows and causes BI to crash.

Comment: I added the PowerBI tag to see if someone from there can help.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually helpful to provide an example of what you have tried, but assuming I understand your requirements, you're likely looking for something like this:

```
SELECT date, transaction_type, company, sum(transaction_speed) as total_transaction_speed
FROM table
GROUP BY date, transaction_type, company;
```